# How to perform a wildcard search in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a PostgreSQL database and I need to perform a wildcard search in a specific column. How can I write a query to achieve this?

I have a table called customers with a column name that stores customers names. I want to search for customers whose names start with "Aa" and end with any characters.

Comment: Have you tried `select ... from ... where name LIKE 'Aa'%` This is very basic sql you learn in any introduction to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select *
from users u
where u.name like 'Aa%'
```

Or if you want case insensitive:

```
select *
from users u
where u.name ilike 'Aa%'
```

Postgres also supports regular expressions, but that might be overkill compared to what you want to do. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, you can use the following command:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE name LIKE 'Aa%';
```

If you want to perform a case-insensitive search, you can use the `ILIKE` operator instead

For Apache AGE, you can use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v:customers)
    WHERE v.name STARTS WITH "Aa"
    RETURN v.name
$$) AS (name agtype);
```

You can read more [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/operators.html#starts-with) about Apache AGE operators.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, according to the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/operators.html#starts-with), you can make a case-insensitive search adding `(?i)` at the beginning of the string. For example, if you have a database with the following information:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
CREATE (:Example {name: 'aaaa'}),
       (:Example {name: 'AAAA'}),
       (:Example {name: 'aAaA'}),
       (:Example {name: 'AaAa'})
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

You can perform the following case-insensitive search and return the following results:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
        MATCH (v:Example)
        WHERE v.name =~ '(?i)Aa'
        RETURN v.name
$$) AS (names agtype);

 names  
--------
 "aaaa"
 "AAAA"
 "aAaA"
 "AaAa"
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for customers names that starts with "Aa" with this script:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE name LIKE 'Aa%';
```

If you are looking the case insensitive, so in that case you can use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`